# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT having all values same

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM charges WHERE (
  charges.id not in (
    select charge_id from billing_invoice_charges where is_deactivated = 0
  )
)
```

I need to convert it into a JOIN QUERY, so I'm trying:

```
SELECT charges.id, group_concat(bic.is_deactivated) AS active_statuses 
FROM charges LEFT JOIN billing_invoice_charges AS bic
ON bic.charge_id = charges.id GROUP BY charges.id

HAVING .......; <--- Check if all values are 1's
```

The output of GROUP_CONCAT is:

```
+------+-----------------+
| id   | active_statuses |
+------+-----------------+
|    2 | 0,1,1           |
|    3 | 1,1             |
|    6 | 1               |
|    7 | 1,1,1           |
|   12 | 0,0,1           |
+------------------------+
```

How can I check if all the values if `active_statuses` in HAVING clause are 1's? This should give me the `charges` I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a `HAVING` clause which uses conditional aggregation to ensure that no non `1` statuses occur for each group.

```
SELECT
    charges.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(bic.is_deactivated) AS active_statuses 
FROM charges
LEFT JOIN billing_invoice_charges AS bic
    ON bic.charge_id = charges.id
GROUP BY charges.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN bic.is_deactivated <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT
    charges.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(bic.is_deactivated) AS active_statuses 
FROM charges
LEFT JOIN billing_invoice_charges AS bic
ON bic.charge_id = charges.id
GROUP BY charges.id
HAVING active_statuses NOT LIKE '%0%'
```

which should ignore any results with a 0 in active_statuses

Comment: Well, this also worked for me with a slight addition `HAVING active_statuses NOT LIKE '%0%' OR active_statuses IS NULL`. But, as per my question this is right !!!